# Matrix operation without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which contain the geometric coordinates of 5 points.

```
centroids = [x1,x2;...;x5,y5]
```

I want to build a matrix who contain the distance with all other points.

```
distance  =

     inf         pt1-pt2     pt1-pt3     pt1-pt4     pt1-pt5
     pt2-pt1     inf         pt2-pt3     pt2-pt4     pt2-pt5
     pt3-pt3     pt3-pt2     inf         pt3-pt4     pt3-pt5
     pt4-pt1     pt4-pt2     pt4-pt3     inf         pt4-pt5
     pt5-pt1     pt5-pt2     pt5-pt3     pt5-pt4     inf
```

I use inf because then I want to take the min with the index of each line [value,index]=min(distance(.....)).

The objectif is to have a final matrix like this :

```
result =
     indice_of_the_closest      dist
     indice_of_the_closest      dist
     indice_of_the_closest      dist
     indice_of_the_closest      dist
     indice_of_the_closest      dist
```

I achieve to do this with a loop but I need some help to do this without loop.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the statistics toolbox you can do something like this

```
% Compute the pair-wise distances
d = sqrt((x(:,1) - x(:,1).').^2 + (x(:,2) - x(:,2).').^2);

% If you are on MATLAB < 2016b
% d = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus, x(:,1), x(:,1).').^2 + bsxfun(@minus, x(:,2), x(:,2).').^2);

% Set the diagonal to Inf
d(logical(eye(size(d)))) = Inf;

% Find the minimum distance and index
[mindist, ind] = min(d, [], 1);

% Create the output matrix
result = [ind(:), mindist(:)];
```

If you *do* have the statistics toolbox, you can use [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) to find the closest *two* points to each point (the first closest is the point itself)

```
[inds, dists] = knnsearch(x, x, 'k', 2);
result = [inds(:,2), dists(:,2)];
```

Comment: Can you explain me in more details the solution for MATLAB < 2016b ?
I cannot understand exactly. Thanks